# Intercept exceptions thrown by repository method with different error codes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to intercept `DataAccessException` that is thrown by data-layer (`@Repository`) with knowing which method is causing this exception?

Writing custom `SQLExceptionTranslator` does not fit my need as I cannot determine which method caused the exception.

I have a repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {
    @ErrorCode("E1000")
    User findById(int id);
    
    @ErrorCode("E1001")
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

`ErrorCode` is a custom annotation holds an error code that I need to send to client whenever `DataAccessException` occurs.

If there is a way to intercept the call to `findById` with catching `DataAccessException`, then it is easy to extract error code from annotation and re-throw a custom exception that can be catched by exception handler.

Comment: It is better if we could do it without Spring AOP.

Comment: Can't think of a way without Spring AOP, so I've still posted an answer with it in case of no one finds a better approach.

Comment: Why can't you determine the method causing the exception? It should be in the stacktrace of exception which is available in a SQLExceptionTranslator. There is a problem though with this approach since the method that throws the exception and the one _causing_ it might be completely different due to JPAs write behind cache and lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Spring AOP is allowed, you could build your own aspect, for example:

```
@Aspect
public class ErrorCodeAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(errorCode)")
    public Object aroundErrorCode(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, ErrorCode errorCode) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
            throw new YourCustomException(errorCode.value(), dae);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that annotations on interface methods are *not* inherited by implementing class methods (even with [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) which applies to parent *classes* only), so you will probably need to annotate your concrete service classes instead for the aspect to plug in (unless Spring does some additional black magic with the repository proxies I wouldn't be aware of).

Answer (score 0):

You can define the custom `ExceptionHandler`.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionResolver {
    @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoSuchElementException(DataAccessException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(yourErrorCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get `yourErrorCode` ?

Comment: Oh, I see. You need do get the error code that declared as an annotation. Then I guess you have use Spring AOP and custom exception approach.